# Problem with new Pay Later contributions showing as Completed

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, paylater

I'm a very new CiviCRm user. And pretty new to WordPress so I apologise if this is a user error. I'm doing suitability testing.

WordPress 4.8

CiviCRM 4.7.20

I have created a Contribution page to take memberships. I believe I've selected the options I need for membership types and pricing.

At the moment, I ONLY have a Pay Later option. I haven't tried yet with PayPal or similar.

So in my test I create a new user, put in the information needed. And submit it.

I then go and find that user, and look at the relevant contribution. It shows as completed, not pending.

Obviously this is incorrect.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Norman

Answer (score 2):

It depends highly on the membership amount you display on the contribution page. If the amount is `0`, there is no pending state needed and contribution directly gets set to Completed.

So, I think you should check the `Minimum Fee` set for the membership type you've selected on this page.

Comment: There's definitely a price set.

I've tested a bit more.

There's an option in the Contribute page settings to allow other contributions at the same time.

So I have a member price ($10) and a contribution with $200 option plus other and a "no thanks" option.

If I select the extra contribution option, with the $200 then it goes through and shows as Pending (Pay Later) as I would expect.

However, if I just choose the membership option, and select "No Thanks" for the extra contribution, then the membership option shows as payed.

This seems like a bug?

Cheers,
Norm

Comment: yes, that should be recorded as pending and no thanks options should not create any contribution record. Can you check on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and see if you can replicate the same behaviour there too ? If yes, please file a [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org)

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior on the demo server. 

However, I can't create an account on the Jira (CiviCRM) page because it insists my email is already in use. But when I use the "Send password" option it says it can't find my email address...

I'll try contacting the info email address. Unless there is a better place to contact.

Comment: Cool, You can file a jira issue with steps needed to replicate and if possible submit a pull request for the patch against civicrm github https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core.